# MultiValueDictKeyError at /boardeditor/

Tags: django

I have a template that generates 2 forms. The forms are used to retrieve data via POST

The problem is when a user tamper with the data via POST for instance delete the input attribute name called process .

-----------------------------4827543632391\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"\r\n\r\nYWSIqoP9MjdKYlauwT5fSdxtFH2rcoaH\r\n-----------------------------4827543632391\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="board"\r\n\r\n\r\n-----------------------------4827543632391\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="process"\r\n\r\ndelete\r\n-----------------------------4827543632391--\r\n

I get this error If the user delete the value process from the name.

How can I combat this error and prevent users from tampering with the form.

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /whiteboardeditor/

Key 'process' not found in <QueryDict: {u'': [u'delete'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken':     [u'YWSIqoP9MjdKYlauwT5fSdxtFH2rcoaH'], u'board': [u'2']}>
File "C:\o\17\mysite\pet\views.py" in WhiteBoardEditor
  362.             if request.POST['process'] == 'primary':
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  258.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError("Key %r not found in %r" % (key, self))

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /whiteboardeditor/
Exception Value: Key 'process' not found in <QueryDict: {u'': [u'delete'],     u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'YWSIqoP9MjdKYlauwT5fSdxtFH2rcoaH'], u'board': [u'2']}>
```

My html

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}
    {{ boardpicture.as_p }}
<input type = "hidden" name="process" value= "primary" />
<input type = "submit" value= "save" />
 </form>

      {% for p in picture %}
 <li><a href ="{% url world:delpic p.id 1 %}">{{p.description}}</a>
 {% endfor %}




 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}
    {{ picturedelete.as_p }}
    <input type = "hidden" name="process" value= "delete" />
    <input type = "submit" value= "save" />

 </form>

 </form>
 {% for pi in pict %}
 <li><a href ="{% url world:delpic pi.id 2 %}">{{ pi.description }}</a>
 {% endfor %}
```

My views.py

```
def WhiteBoardEditor(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))
picture = {}
pict = {}

if request.method == "POST":
        forms = WhiteBoardPictureForm(request.user,request.POST,)
        formss = PictureDeleteForm(request.user,request.POST,)
        if request.POST['process'] == 'primary':
            if forms.is_valid():
                board = forms.cleaned_data['board']
            if board:
                boards = forms.cleaned_data['board']
                picture = Picture.objects.filter(board=boards)
            return render(request,'boardeditor.html',{
                'picture':picture, 
                'boardpicture':WhiteBoardPictureForm(request.user), 
                'picturedelete':PictureDeleteForm(request.user)})

        elif request.POST['process'] == 'delete':
            if formss.is_valid():
                pooh = formss.cleaned_data['board']
                if pooh:
                    pooh = formss.cleaned_data['board']
                    pict = Picture.objects.filter(board=pooh)
            return render(request,'boardeditor.html',{
            'pict':pict, 
            'boardpicture':WhiteBoardPictureForm(request.user), 
            'picturedelete':PictureDeleteForm(request.user)})

            return render(request,'boardeditor.html',{'board':WhiteBoardNameForm(request.user),'boardpicture':WhiteBoardPictureForm(request.user),'picturedelete':PictureDeleteForm(request.user)})
```

My views.py

```
class WhiteBoardPictureForm(forms.ModelForm):

        def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
                super(WhiteBoardPictureForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                self.fields['board'].queryset = Board.objects.filter(user=user)

    class Meta:
        model = Picture 
        fields = ('board',)

class PictureDeleteForm(forms.ModelForm):

        def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
                super(PictureDeleteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                self.fields['board'].queryset = Board.objects.filter(user=user)

    class Meta:
        model = Picture 
        fields = ('board',)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should validate the forms before processing, like `form.is_valid()` and return appropriate
page with form and errors if its not valid.

If forms are valid use `form.cleaned_data` for posted data rather than `request.POST`.

Here is how to use forms [Using forms in view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view)

So either you can add `process` input field in the form.

Or for this specific instance, you can add a check in your view before processing form as

```
if request.POST.has_key('process'):
    # return error
```

Comment: Rohan If the user deletes csrfmiddlewaretoken . I get this error CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. . I'm having trouble combating this error . Could you please help me out Thank you Rohan

Comment: @donkeyboy72, that is django's feature to protect against Cross site referencing. Check the documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/ and see what and how you can do.